# Javascript function push problem

Tags: javascript, list, function, object

i've following JS function.

```
responseData:function(resp){
    this.jsondata = eval('(' + resp + ')');
    this.propList = [];
    for (var i = 0;i<this.jsondata.length;i++) {
        for (obj in this.jsondata[i]) {
            alert(obj); //shows the property name of obj
            this.propList.push({
                obj : this.jsondata[i][obj] //insert only simple obj string
            });
        }
    }
    return this.propList;
}
```

I want to insert in my propList the property name and the value, but instead inserting the property name this function inserts simple 'obj' as a string. What i'm doing wrong?

greetings
Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the loop to,

```
    for (obj in this.jsondata[i]) {
        alert(obj); //shows the property name of obj
        var item = {};
        item[obj] = this.jsondata[i][obj];
        this.propList.push(item);
    }
```

When you use object-literal to create an object the property names are not evaluated as variables.  To specify the name of an objects property using a variables current value, you must use the `obj[variable]` format.  This will create a property within `obj` whose name will be the same as current value of `variable`.